# AIX - awk display first occurence of each match

Tags: bash, unix, awk, scripting, aix

Let's say i have a file called RESULTS.txt with the following content:

```
SUCCESS JON DOE
SUCCESS JON DOE
SUCCESS JANE DOE
FAILURE JON DOE
FAILURE JANE DOE
```

What i need to do now is to 'extract' the name (JON DOE or JANE DOE) from each line that contains the word 'SUCCESS'. I figured this out with awk:
`awk '/SUCCESS/ {print $2 $3}'\; RESULTS.txt` Which gives me the following output:

```
JON DOE
JON DOE
JANE DOE
```

The extraction of the names works fine. My problem now is that i need each match, or in this context each name, only one time. In other words: I want a command which produces the following output:

```
JON DOE
JANE DOE
```

I know one possibility would be to write a script and, for example, store each match into an array. Then i could loop through the array searching if there's already an entry with the same name before inserting a new one.

But what i am looking for is a lean solution to solve this problem without working with arrays or writing into a file.

I'm working on an AIX machine.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$1=="SUCCESS" && !a[$2,$3]++{print $2,$3}' RESULTS.txt
```

The output:

```
JON DOE
JANE DOE
```

---

Alternative approach using ***sed*** + ***uniq*** pipeline:

```
sed -n 's/SUCCESS \(.*\)/\1/p' RESULTS.txt | uniq
```

Comment: Works like a charm. I used it like this so it doesn't matter where the "SUCCESS" appears `awk '/SUCCESS/ && !a[$2$3]++{print $2,$3}' RESULTS.txt`

Comment: @EdMorton, good point. I started with separator `a[$2,$3]`, but prematurely simplified to `a[$2$3]`. Returned to the relevant "key"

Answer (score 0):

***sort*** approach:

```
awk '/SUCCESS/ {print $2 " " $3}' RESULTS.txt | sort -ur
```

Output:

```
JON DOE
JANE DOE
```

Comment: What's the `\;` for? Also that script will not produce the output you say it does (hints: missing `,` and wrong sort order).

Answer (score 0):

No arrays in sight, as requested:

```
$ awk 'sub(/^SUCCESS /,"") && $0!=prev{print; prev=$0}' file
JON DOE
JANE DOE
```